# J2ME Hexidecimal String to Integer

Tags: string, java-me, integer, hex

Is there a way to convert a `String` (in hex format) into a `Integer`? I know of `Integer.parseInt(string, 16)`, but it does not handle the `0x` prefix. I'm looking something to the effect of `Integer.decode(string)` from standard Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you consider an option to use [substring(2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to cut off the `0x` prefix prior to invoking `parseInt`?

Comment: Yes I have, but I would prefer to do without the if statement.

Hm, I thought I had talked about cutting off the prefix when I mentioned parseInt(string, 16), but I guess not. I was hoping for something simple that I hadn't considered, but I guess there isn't a simple solution to this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int convert(String s) {
    int base = 10;
    if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("0x")) {
        base = 16;
        s = s.substring(2);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(s, base);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that J2ME would be able to do this for me, I will just use this method then. Thanks.